# Tomar el numero máximo de id relacionado, con un campo

Tags: mysql

[image: Accidente tablas]Tengo

----SELECT accidente_comision.id_comision from accidente INNER JOIN accidente_comision ON accidente.id=id_acd.

Y quiero obtener el numero máximo de id, relacionado con la tabla accidente a comisión, supongamos tengo 4 comisiones atendiendo un accidente

para eso tengo una tabla que toma el id de accidente y la misma numero de id de comisión.

al arrojar la consulta me muestra 
1
2
3
4

pero la cosa es tomar el numero max.... es decir que la consulta me arroje 
4

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Para poder responderte es recomendable que pongas la estructura de las tablas involucradas.

Comment: como lo hago? ... :c

Comment: Por ejemplo, pon los comandos usados para crear esas tablas. Si no las creaste tu y existen ya los puedes obtener con SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_de_tabla;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que necesitas es usar un **GROUP BY** y un MAX():

```
SELECT accidente_comision.id_comision, MAX(id_acd) 
FROM accidente 
INNER JOIN accidente_comision 
    ON accidente.id=id_acd
GROUP BY accidente_comision.id_comision
```

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por responder :3

Comment: @CarlosAlbertoSolerVelasquez Si te ha ayudado haz click en la marca verde para aceptar la respuesta.

Comment: porque se utiliza la función GROUP BY ? si la utilizo me arroja otro resultado en la consulta que tiene todos los id no solamente el max ...

Comment: El GRPUP BY lo que hace es agruparte en base a los campos declarados en el SELECT. Y el MAX lo que hace es traerte el valor maximo. En conjunto la sentencia los que hace es agruparte x cada accidente_comision.id_comision su maximo id_acd.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esto, teoricamente la subconsulta debe traer 1 solo registro, y, como se ordena desc(descendentemente) tomará el último id, lo cual hará que que cuando se compara en`where accidente_comision.id=(...` sea forzosamente el último id.

```
SELECT accidente_comision.id_comision from accidente INNER JOIN accidente_comision ON accidente.id=id_acd.
where accidente_comision.id=(Select top 1 accidente_comision.id order by accidente_comision.id desc)
```